# Adding kernel density output to map with ArcPy

Tags: arcmap, arcpy, density

I am trying to emulate the behavior of the Kernel Density tool from the ArcMap 10 GUI in a script; in other words, I want to calculate the density of a dataset, and add the visual result to a map. If possible, I'd also like to be able to adjust the color and transparency of the kernel density layer, as one can in the layer properties dialog in the GUI.

I know one can run the kernel density tool in a script, but I am not sure how to add the output to the map like the GUI does. Is it possible to do this in ArcPy?

Comment: I may be missing something, but in the example there, they have .tif files originally. The output I have from the kDens is an entire folder of 6 .adf files. How can I add these to a map in arcpy?

Answer (score 2):

AddLayer should help

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/AddLayer/00s300000025000000/